# Swift framework: Swift generated header doesn't contain modules I need

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I've created a Swift framework and when I build it I get a generated header file called `MyApp-Swift`. In the header, all the methods are available for Objective-C users to implement. However, the header can't recognize `NSString` in the method's parameter. For example

```
- (void)getFirstName:(NSString *)lastName;
```

This method raises the error

> Unknown type name NSString

I've checked some frameworks on GitHub and they seem to get around this by having the `@import Foundation` in the `_has_feature(modules)` section of the generated header file. However, I only have `@import ObjectiveC` in this section.

```
 #if __has_feature(modules)
 @import ObjectiveC;
 #endif
```

How can I get this section of my header file to include the `Foundation` module so I won't get an error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Any updates?